# How to make grub2 boot another drive MBR?

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, mbr, grub2

My laptop (DELL Vostro 3350) have two hard drives:
1- /dev/sda , ssd with Ubuntu14.04 , grub2 installed to this MBR. *Installed on normaly hd bay* 
2- /dev/sdb , stock hd (with recovery partition etc etc) *in place of dvd drive with an adapter*

I cannot figure out how to boot Windows from grub2. In the past I remember that (maybe with grub1) I can point to second disk mbr and then Windows boots normally.

So my config is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 15566 cilindri, totale 250069680 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x0007d87d

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   175781887    87889920   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       175783934   250068991    37142529    5  Esteso
/dev/sda5       175783936   246163455    35189760   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       246165504   250068991     1951744   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 60801 cilindri, totale 976773168 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0xb3e7a9bf

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048      206847      102400   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sdb2          206848    30926847    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3   *    30926848   167600175    68336664    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       167604160   976768064   404581952+   f  W95 Esteso (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       167606208   976768064   404580928+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

here is my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` section of os-prober

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (su /dev/sdb2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-CC70378A703779F2' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd1,msdos2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos2  CC70378A703779F2
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root CC70378A703779F2
fi
parttool ${root} hidden-
chainloader +1
}

menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (su /dev/sdb3)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-AC7C4EC27C4E86D4' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd1,msdos3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos3  AC7C4EC27C4E86D4
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AC7C4EC27C4E86D4
fi
parttool ${root} hidden-
chainloader +1
}
```

both give me this message if i selected them on boot menu:

```
error: no such device: CC70378A703779F2 (or AC7C4EC27C4E86D4)
error: hd1 cannot get C/H/S values
```

[image]

last, but not the least, from my BIOS i **cannot change hard drive boot priority** so there's no way to boot `/dev/sdb` first.

edit:

this is my `blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="1597fe18-faf5-48a5-b80f-4cbb7f8b896e" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="ea6548f1-3004-49ff-8d1d-4c84dfed3a6a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="e24dbc3b-d2da-4a63-97ce-7430cfce9fce" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="DELLUTILITY" UUID="3030-3030" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="CC70378A703779F2" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="OS" UUID="AC7C4EC27C4E86D4" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="VostroHD" UUID="01CCBB70E50A71E0" TYPE="ntfs"
```

EDIT:
i ran `bootinfo` script. [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/glauc1ahdjhrjn0/bootinfo.txt) the result

EDIT2:
pc configuration at top

Answer (score 0):

Although you use Ubuntu and not Arch Linux (and didn't specify which Windows version you use), this may help you.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Dual-booting

Comment: i've updated my question